# error : cannot include iconv.h while building c application to parse xml using libxml2

Tags: c, libxml2

I am using libxml2 to parse xml but on compiling the solution it throws

`fatal error : cannot open iconv.h`

When i have placed the `iconv.h` there and rebuild again then again it throws other

`error unable to open include file sys/cdefs.h.`

i am ending up in a vicious circle . please help

Comment: What build environment? It sounds like you don't have the right iconv.h for your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build and Install libiconv on your machine and it will work

Comment: i have downloaded libinconv 1.7 but unable to find how to build or install it. i am using VS 2010 on windows 64 bit but want to compile application for 32 bit and hence using libxml2 for 32 bit

Comment: @priya can you post link from where u have download that?

Comment: @priya this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429101/building-the-latest-iconv-and-libxml2-binaries-in-win32

Comment: hi, I have downloaded it from ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/win32/iconv-1.9.2.win32.zip

Comment: now i have successfully compiled my solution but on debugging it throws error : can't start zlib1.dll missing. please help

Comment: Download Compile and install zlib

Comment: hi,done with all this this link is really helpful for downloading all dependencies with libxml2: ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/